# My keyboard types question marks instead of "Georgia" letters

Tags: keyboard, typing

I have a problem with typing in Georgian language. Our letters are not Latin and looks like "ა,ბ,გ,დ,ე,ღ" etc. when I type in Warcraft or Quiz Builder i get question marks instead of the text i want. What is wrong?

[image]

EDIT
Georgian letters work properly on other applications.

Comment: I suspect the keyboard is just fine.  It's the displaying that's mucked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Georgian letters work correctly in other applications, it would mean that this is not a keyboard issue but a software issue.  For example, Warcraft and Quiz Builder may not support Georgian.

Maybe your encoding is set wrongly?  You probably should be using Unicode; check if these applications support Unicode and how to tell them to use it.

Comment: It's possible that these programs don't support Georgian because they were written using the "ANSI" APIs rather than Unicode ones; this is particularly common for Win9x-era programs where the Unicode mode didn't even exist.